# Reference web config of parent project to child project in same Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web, web-config

I am having an existing website which contains two directories a website and a class library file.
now am trying to add new web application to this,when I added it creates a web config for it. 
How can i reference my new web application to refer from my website

[image]

For your reference,If I am doing something wrong please guide.

Thanks
Askar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a web application to a website.
If it is needed that you cn make calls via Service reference or ajax calls.
But you might have an issue with CORS than.
the question is why are you trying to put in one solution a web application AND a web service.

I think you should have one web application from which you create all the controls you need and refer the needed class libraries

Comment: Actually this is what am trying to do,I have a fully developed website(actually its a web application,but I think it has been developed as website,bcoz it was not developed my me),Now I need to add another module in that application,so instead of creating it at root directory,I need to put my development as a new project.thats what am trying to do.

Comment: Similar to something like this [Multiple Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8129/Separating-an-ASP-NET-Web-Application-into-multipl)